# Passbook pass immediately updates when added

Tags: passbook

I noticed that when I add a pass, the pass is immediately updated.

That is when I click 'Add', my service that returns a list of Serial Numbers is invoked and then subsequently the call is made to update the pass.

I thought the call that gets the list of Serial Numbers is only invoked when it receives a message from the apple push notification service. But it looks like once it is done registering, this method that gets the serial numbers is immediately invoked

I am following [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html)

The uri to register the device looks like the following...

> https://webservice/PassbookService/v1/devices/32l5kj2lk5236262lj/registrations/pass.com.mypass/11111

and then the call which invokes my method to return a list of serial numbers looks like the following

> https://webservice/PassbookService/v1/devices/32l5kj2lk5236262lj/registrations/pass.com.mypass

I guess is it normal that the 'Getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device' method is automatically invoked once the pass is added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct behaviour.  Passes containing the webServiceURL are dynamic by nature but they can be distributed as static files.  A .pkpass bundle delivered by email could potentially be 'stale' when it is installed and so Passbook automatically calls the web service to fetch the latest version.